# Javafx change view during runtime and save the new one

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I am searching for a way to change the view of an JavaFX FXML Application during runtime and save the result so, that it is present at the next Application start. Is there a way? I was searching the WWW but dont find any solution! For example: I have a function where i can add a label to a GridPane and can save the new added label. At the next start of my Application, the new label is present. Its for an DB Application where the user can add new Database fields for custom data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, by using properties file(or DataBase) you can achieve this. Before closing the application update the current status into properties file. So that while opening the application once again read the properties file and update it to the previous status.

Comment: Can you give me an example for an properties entry?

Comment: The eclipse saves the selected workspace in the properties file, so that it can be retrieved for the next run. So do you want example on code?